# Is this a correct way to determine which groups are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

Question: Determine which of the following groups are isomorphic.

$C_{4} \times C_{6} \times C_{21}$

$C_{3} \times C_{7} \times C_{24}$

$C_{2} \times C_{9} \times C_{28}$

$C_{3} \times C_{12} \times C_{14}$

Answer: We have that every finite abelian group is isomorphic to a unique canonical (see my comment below to have a definition of what canonical means!) direct product of finite cyclic groups so it suffices to determine which unique product each of the groups above are isomorphic to.

For $C_{4} \times C_{6} \times C_{21}$ we have $C_{4} \times C_{6} \times C_{21} \cong C_{4} \times (C_{2} \times C_{3}) \times (C_{3} \times C_{7})$ since $2,3$ and $3,7$ are coprime.

Reordering the products doesn't change the fact the groups are isomorphic

$(C_{2} \times C_{4}) \times (C_3\times C_{3}) \times C_{7}$ from here it is easy to take the last term in each product (they are pairwise coprime) and join them together to get the following canonical direct product.

$C_{6} \times C_{84}$.

So $C_{6} \times C_{84} \cong C_{4} \times C_{6} \times C_{21}$.

Following the same method we discover the remaining three groups are isomorphic to:

$C_{3} \times C_{168}$

$C_{2} \times C_{252}$

$C_{6} \times C_{84}$

respectively.

Hence the only isomorphic groups are the first and last group on the list.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked your bookkeeping, but often the "canonical" product has only factors of _prime power order_, e.g., the first group is $C_{2} \times C_{4} \times C_{3} \times C_{3} \times C_{7}$. It appears you have a different definition of "canonical"...?

Comment: Canonical in my course is used to mean $n_i|n_{i+1}$ for each $i$ in the product except the last one. So $C_3 \times C_6 \times  C_{66}$ would be a canonical product because $3 \mid 6 \mid 66$.

Comment: Yes $A \times B$ is isomorphic to $B \times A$ by the mapping that maps $(a,b)$ to $(b,a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the comment by Andrew D.Hwang to see if you're correct.

Here, I use his definition of canonical product.

The four groups are respectively then isomorphic to :

$C_4 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_3 \times C_7$

$C_3\times C_7 \times C_8\times C_3$

$C_2\times C_9 \times C_7 \times C_4$

$C_3\times C_3\times C_4 \times C_2 \times C_7$

Rearranging the terms does not change the isomorphism, and so we get that indeed only the first and fourth groups are isomorphic, as you yourself proved.